# Windows 8.1 Update - Uninstall Sentinel

Tags: windows-8

I am not very computer savvy on anything Windows 8.  I am trying to upgrade from Windows 8 on my new computer to Windows 8.1.

It stops telling me I need to uninstall Sentinel Drivers.  I tried the obvious, but it was not in the list of programs to uninstall.  I then searched the Internet for solutions.  I now have installed it twice in two different places trying to do the different "fixes."  I'm going to the command prompt but can't get it to where it needs to be.  So I believe I now have this Sentinel hasp in three places, two of which I don't know where.  The help I have found, though probably helpful, does not help me because I am lost in Windows 8.  I am beyond frustrated.

Can someone give me very DUMBED-DOWN INSTRUCTIONS on how to get rid of all this so I can move on to installing Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

[Download and run the Cleanup tool](http://www.safenet-inc.com/support-downloads/sentinel-drivers/) to get rid of all drivers.

Comment: This did not get rid of the Sentinel Drivers according to the Windows 8.1 download which still says it can't continue until I uninstall them.

Comment: run regedit.exe and search for **Sentinel** and remove all entries you can find.

Comment: I did regedit.exe and it took me out of command prompt and brought up windows.  So I just did a computer search and found 45 entries with sentinel.  Do I just delete them all or just the .dll files?  Will this cause more problems because I'm not uninstalling?

Comment: I have no idea how deep it writes into the system. You can export each key into a different .reg file so that you import the settings back or better make a system restore point. Now delete all entries you find